# Failed to parse time no eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, orm, laravel-8

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

`select('id','title', 'description', 'author',  DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d/%m/%Y') AS created_at"))->get();`

quando executo ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

`erro": "Could not parse '19/06/2021': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (19/06/2021) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character`

vale resaltar os teste que eu fiz e percebi que:

1 -  mudando o alias (AS) para outro nome como created ele formata normalmente, porém preciso que  o nome seja realmente created_at;

2 - Funciona no mysql mesmo usando o alias o nome created_at

3 - se no lugar da formatação eu usar %d-%m-%Y ele tbm funciona

a versão do laravel q estou usando é a v.8.

**OBS**: Sei que pode chegar alguma pessoa e falar para formatar no php ou na view, porém se trata de uma api, por esse motivo ela ja deve ir formatada com o nome 'created_at'

Comment: A questão é o formato da data utilizada. Ao ler a documentação do PHP, verá que quando utilizada a barra como separador da data, o formato que será esperado será mês/dia/ano. Como não existe o mês 19 dá erro. Quando você retorna com hífen, funciona, pois o formato esperado passa a ser dia-mês-ano. Resumindo, mude para hífen, ou coloque o mês antes do dia na formatação da data. Mas... por que precisa do `date_format` na SQL?

Comment: o valor que vem do banco  é '2021-06-19 03:58:02', uso o date_format para deixar formatado como  '19/06/2021'. Mas a questão é, por q quando eu mudo o meu alias para created ele funciona?  se fosse relamente o erro do php ele retornaria mesmo eu mudando o meu alias.

Comment: Porque o `created_at` é tratado como data pelo laravel, já o `created` apenas não, mas só como string

Comment: Cuidado ao utilizar DATE_FORMAT nas suas queries.Imagina aplicar DATE_FORMAT em 1 milhão de registros. Sua consulta irá ficar muito lenta. 
Recomendo as leituras https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting e https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: interessante, obg pela dica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro parece que não tem nada haver com a query, e sim no momento que o Laravel tenta instanciar o eloquent, [ele transforma os campos created_at e updated_at em um tipo Carbon/DateTime](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps) por padrão.
Você pode tirar essa funcionalidade do Laravel usando `public $timestamps = false;` no modelo, mas ai deve gerenciar o created_at e updated_at manualmente quando for criar/atualizar o registro.

A solução que indico é [customizar a serialização](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#customizing-the-date-format-per-attribute) deste campo, dispensando fazer na query, usando:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y'
];
```

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado pela dica!